# Proving a matrix statement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C$ be an $m\times n$ matrix in echelon form. Let $\textbf{e}_{j}$ denote the $j$-th standard basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, so that the $i$-th entry of $\textbf{e}_{j}$ is $\delta_{ij}$.

(i) Show that the matrix-vector equation $C\textbf{x}=\textbf{e}_{i}$ has a solution $\textbf{x}$ if and only if the $i$-th row of $C$ is non-zero.

(ii) Using the previous part, show that the matrix-vector equation $C\textbf{x}=\textbf{c}$ has a solution for any vector $\textbf{c}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ if and only if every row of $C$ is non-zero.

Formally, you are being asked to prove that the proposition

$$(\forall\textbf{c}\in\mathbb{R}^{n})(\exists\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{m})\quad C\textbf{x} = \textbf{c}$$ is equivalent to the proposition that every row of $C$ is non-zero.

Now I have completed part (i) and (ii) but I was trying to link it to the proposition and came up with the problem that since $C$ has dimension $m\times n$ and $\textbf{x}$ has dimension $m$ then the matrix-vector multiplication is undefined. Is this a mistake in the question or my understanding?

Comment: Are you sure that's the full statement of what you want to prove? It's definitely false in general, e.g. for $C = 0$ and $\mathbf{c}\neq 0$ there can be no such $\textbf{x}$.

Comment: Ah yes I did miss out the fact that this only holds iff every row of $C$ is non-zero.

Comment: I think $C$ is $n\times m$ and has to be full rank.

Comment: Every row being non-zero is not enough. @PA6OTA is right. You might want to check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem) out.

Comment: Yeah I understand the first part. What does being "full rank" mean?

Comment: $C=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $c=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. What is the $x$ which makes this work?

Comment: Tyler, every row must be non-zero.

Comment: How about $C = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $c=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ then?

Comment: Pretty sure every row there is non-zero. If you want every entry to be non-zero, do the same exercise with $C=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Also, full rank is still not enough. You also need dimension constraints.

Comment: I have no idea what you guys are talking about, can you speak as if you're talking to someone who has just started a first year linear algebra course, thanks!

Comment: "Full rank" means the rows are linearly independent.

Comment: I will edit this and write the full question, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Sorry if we seem harsh, we're just trying to find out what kind of answer do you need.

Comment: That's perfectly fine! I have updated the question @MarcinŁoś

Comment: Echelon form was an important hypothesis.

Comment: Yeah, echelon form is crucial for the question :)

Comment: I understand how to do the question I am just wondering whether the proposition is written incorrectly since by the proposition we have $C\textbf{x} = \textbf{c}$ but $C$ has dimension $m\times n$ and $\textbf{x}$ has dimension $m$. So the multiplication would be undefined.. i.e take a $m=3$ and $n=2$ and let $$C=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \textbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$$ Then $C\textbf{x}$ cannot be found.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I believe it's indeed a mistake in the question. Still, it's true if $C$ is $n\times m$.